# How to use the toggle() feature correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle() script that changes a form. What the user does is click on an image with the id "comp". This then changes the label to New Company and the select drop down changes to a text input. But how do I make it so it toggles back to its original state?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newcomp').click(function() {
        $('select#company').toggle(); 
        $('select#company').replaceWith("<input type='text' id='company' name='company' >");
        $('#comp label').replaceWith('<label for="company">New Company</label>')
    });
});
</script>
```

Regards
Gambit

Comment: Can you post your markup/create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Little confused on `#newcomp` and `#comp`. You say `click on an image with the id "comp"`, should `#newcomp` in your example then not be `#comp`? You also have to post the HTML as we only see the new values you use to replace the label and dropdown with. We have no idea what the original values are you want to switch back to. Knowing those is going to be relevant for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is  `fadeOut->replace->fadeIn.`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newcomp').click(function () {
        $('select#company').fadeOut('slow', function() {
             $('#comp label').replaceWith('<label for="company">New Company</label>');
             $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='company' name='company' >").fadeIn('slow');
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think OP is only showing the code which replaces the original elements. Both lines of code are required in the 1 change. OP seems to be looking for a trigger to undo both `replaceWidth` calls but for that we need the original HTML which was replaced. Fade would not fix that.